# Proof that a simple function can take finitely many value

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure, measurable-functions

Let $(\Omega, \Sigma, \mu)$ be a measure space and let $(\mathbb{R}, \mathcal{B})$ be a measurable space. A function $f:\Omega\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is called simple if
$$f(\omega)=\sum_{i=1}^{n}c_i\mathcal{X}_{A_i},$$
where $c_i\geq0$, $A_i\in\Sigma$, and $\mathcal{X}_{A_i}$ denotes the indicator function.

Now I have to prove that $f(\omega)$ takes finitely many values. In order to prove it, I do the following:

The set $\{c_1, c_2,...,c_n\}$ has the maximum number of all possible combinations as
$$D=\sum_{k=1}^{n} {n\choose k}.$$
So, the function $f(\omega)$ can have maximum $D+1$ different values, which completes the proof.

Please correct me if my proof is wrong and if anyone would like to shed some light on it!

Comment: Check your definition at the top of "simple". It seems your lower indeex on the sum should be $1,$ rather than $i.$

Comment: $D+1$, for the possibility of none of the $c_i$

Comment: @coffeemath ; Yes, I have edited my question, thank you!

Comment: @jcneek : Yes, you are right, I have edited my question. Thank you!

Comment: @Robin Typically, simple functions are defined so that the $A_i$ are mutually disjoint, so that you don't need to worry about sums of $c_i$. So, the number of distinct possible values of $f$ is $n+1$. Also, note that $\sum_{k=1}^n \binom nk = 2^n - 1$.

Comment: @coffeemath At each point $\omega \in \Omega$, the indices $i$ such that $\omega \in A_i$ forms a subset of $\{1,\dots,n\}$. All of these subsets have been accounted for.

Comment: @BenGrossmann ; I assumed that the simple function is written in non-canonical form.

Comment: @BenGrossmann Thanx, got it.

Comment: @BenGrossmann It would not surprise me if several descriptions are used as definition. My favourite definition of simple function is: a measurable function with finite image. Taking its non-empty fibers it provides immediately a partition of the domain.

Comment: @coffeemath ; I am sure about the counting process. I ensured that all types of possible intersections of $A_i$ are accounted for.

Answer (score 1):

Your reasoning seems to be right:

For each point, it will belong to some of the $A_i$'s and therefore the values $f$ can give you are obtained from the partial sums obtained by adding the elements of the subsets contained in  $\{c_i\}_{i = 1}^n$. Which are finite.